# Send selected values from mat-select to controller on button click

Tags: html, angular

I have a bunch of `mat-select`s like this:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>KPI</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let kpi of KpiList" [value]="kpi">{{ kpi.name }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Modifier</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let modifier of ModifierList" [value]="modifier">{{ modifier }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Now, I want to send the selected values with a `(click)` event of a button:

```
  <button mat-button (click)="addComponent(data)">Add Component</button>
```

How do I get both values of the dropdowns to the event handler function? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply add **`ngModel`** to the Select dropdowns.

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>KPI</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="kpiValue">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let kpi of KpiList" [value]="kpi">{{ kpi.name }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Modifier</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="modifierValue">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let modifier of ModifierList" [value]="modifier">{{ modifier }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

In your button function change to something like below

```
 <button mat-button (click)="addComponent(kpiValue,modifierValue)">Add Component</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try binding values of both drop-down to one object and then pass the same object to the event.